# How can I create a USB RAID?

Tags: usb, raid

Reading this [link](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-create-Your-Very-Own-USB-RAID-59976.shtml), it describes how to make a RAID array out of USB sticks, however it describes the process using Gentoo now I don't know about gentoo and have never used it, but I'm supposing this is possible in Ubuntu if so how?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu uses `udev` so you don't need to execute the `mknod` command in those instructions.

As mentioned, `mdadm` is well documented as doesn't care whether the devices are hard disks, usb drives, or even LVM partitions. Examples:

Create a mirrored partition:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --create --level=1 -n 2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

4 disk RAID 5:

```
mdadm /dev/md5 --create --level=5 -n 4 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd2 /dev/sde2
```

Comment: So let's say, I've have 2 USB sticks, how would I go and make a RAID (and which RAID should I choose).

Comment: With 2 USB sticks, the only option is a mirror set, i.e. RAID1.

Answer (score 1):

The guide that you linked will be the same with ubuntu. The raid utility "mdadm" is fairly common and well documented.

You will need to `apt-get install mdadm` to have this tool available.