# Booting Ubuntu from multiple usb

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

Can Ubuntu usb stick be run from a usb divider with another usb as a memory extension? And I have another outrageous idea, is it possible to connect 2 usb in one partition with a usb divider?

Answer (score 0):

I have to wonder if this might be an X/Y problem. What problem are you trying to solve? You can certainly have two USB sticks in a computer, boot from one, and save data onto the other. By default, you should see the non-boot USB below Computer on the left hand side of the Files windows.

For your second question, I doubt that something like this is possible, and again I don't understand why you would want to do this.

Comment: My laptop is partialy broken and i can't boot from hdd sata cable and it doesen'n have a cd. The idea of usb devider is revelant for me because i boot it from usb all of the time but i always brake it becausr i bang it all over the place. So i want to run an usb extension to empty hdd slot and if i could devide it it would be usefull.

Comment: When you say "one partition" do you mean "one USB port"? If so, then yes, as long as the USB hub/divider gives each hard drive or thumb drive sufficient power, you will be able to run multiple external storage devices.

Comment: By partition i ment anactual partition but to clarifie my first question when the bootable usb stick gets filled can i stll download and install thing straight to the second usb stick?

Comment: If you want to create a single virtual hard drive out of multiple USB sticks / drives, this is indeed possible. I'm not sure what hoops would be required to do this, or even if there is existing software that can do it. I believe that what you are describing is essentially a USB RAID array. I'm going to personally recommend that you don't go down this path, but if you wish to, I would start here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172735/how-can-i-create-a-usb-raid